# Connecting 3phase motor to FC

Tags: motor, cables

I'm connecting 3 phase motor to frequency converter and I don't understand why to use **shield** cables. Is using shield cables a must in every situation or only when nearby is running a Profinet or other sensitive signals?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! It’s for EMI reasons. Is your VFD a few years old by any chance?

Comment: I'm using a Rexroth efc5610, it's a new VFD. But this really doesn't matter. OK EMI reasons, why then the main power cable for a machine is not shielded and all other wires in control cabinet, aren't they also producing EMI?

Comment: Not necessarily. VFD is a cost driven business and if you can get away with requiring your customers to use shielded cables on the output, that will save money off the price tag. Mains side though, the government/approval bodies will for sure require EMI levels to be below limits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A variable frequency drive (VFD) uses PWM to simulate a sine wave to the motor. A side effect of this is that PWM signals are very noisy. The shield on the VFD cable is to *contain* the noise generated by the PWM signal from affecting nearby equipment. You're 100% correct that it would be poor practice to run this past a Profinet cable.

Is it a must in every situation? Probably not. However, most manufacturer's will strongly suggest that you use their VFD cables. The shield adds some robustness to the cable that comes in handy in industrial environments and in general they're built pretty heavy duty. If you're building to industrial standards (CSA or UL) it might even be a requirement but I don't have the standards handy.

In my experience, adding a shield is just a good way to go. Say you build a nice controls cabinet with VFD cables that have no shield and some 24 VDC hard-wired signals on the door. The chance that in 10 years someone wants to upgrade and add remote HMI displays, or SCADA compatibility, is pretty high. It would suck to have to run new VFD cables if the non-shielded ones caused too much noise.

Answer (score 0):

A VFD may work with **PWM**. These **step functions** have a broad frequency width, and in case of a 3-phase motor, most probably the current is in the 2 or 3 digits Ampere range at certain times like starting under load etc.
That means, the VFD could emit relatively much power (like a short wave sender does intentionally), if the length of the cable to the motor is - by conincidence - matching certain wavelength conditions like an **antenna**.  Since the frequency bandwidth of PWM is rather wide, the chance to emit some tens, hundreds or even more milliwatt in certain frequency ranges is high.